# Vuetify upgrade error vue-cli and vuetify 2.0

Tags: vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I am new a vue and vuetify, I need to upgrade vuetify v1.5 to v2.1.3. I read documentatıon but ı can't fixed this error :

https://imguploads.net/image/tGzZv

This is my app.vue code :

```
<style lang="sass">
 @import '../node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass';
</style>
```

This is my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import '../src/assets/css/custom.css'
import { i18n } from '@/plugins/i18n'
import '../node_modules/vuetify'  

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueResource)

 import auth from '../src/api/auth'

auth.checkAuth()

   Vue.router = router
  Vue.config.productionTip = false

 new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(opts),
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
 render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to import this in app.vue

```
<style lang="sass">
 @import '../node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass';
</style>
```